# Write object to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, devexpress, devextreme

It is necessary by clicking on register to transfer the object with the filled fields to state `dataChanged`

https://codesandbox.io/s/validation-devextreme-form-fso31

The problem is in the `onFieldDataChanged` property when setting the `dataChanged` state. Error:

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component
>   repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or
>   componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to
>   prevent infinite loops

```
<Form
            formData={customer}
            readOnly={false}
            showColonAfterLabel={true}
            showValidationSummary={true}
            validationGroup="customerData"
            onFieldDataChanged={e => {
              let newData = e.component.option("formData");
              this.setState({
                dataChanged: newData
              });
            }}
>
```

Comment: I dropped a `console.log('field data changed', e.component.option("formData"))` in the callback, seems to be working for me, I see it triggered on blur of the field. Do you have a solid list of repro steps?

Comment: I do not have.
It works fine on codesanbox, but locally this error appears in the project, although everything is the same

Comment: Are they exactly the same, all versions of react, everything from your `package.json` file locally is identical to your sandbox? Your component code doesn't make use of the `componentWillUpdate` or `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle functions. Is there more to the error/warning, like a stack trace, something to help direct where the error originated from?

Comment: exactly the same. Error on row with "this.setState({dataChanged: newData});"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling `setState` in an arrow function as prop, create a function like this:

```
onFieldChangeHandler = (e) => {
    const newData = e.component.option("formData");
    this.setState({
        dataChanged: newData
    });
}
```

And in your `Form` component's props:

```
onFieldDataChanged={this.onFieldChangeHandler}
```

Comment: "ShortForm.jsx:39 Uncaught TypeError: e.persist is not a function".  Without "e.persist" works fine! Is e.persist necessary?

Comment: In your case.. I don't think it is required. I'll modify the answer and remove it!
It is required if you call setState asynchronously as in [this medium article](https://medium.com/@brunogarciagonzalez/reactjs-events-exploration-a295505016f1) and react's official website [second note](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html?). 
If you call it asynchronously, by the time you use `e`, it's already been nullified.